# What's the maximum URL length in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, http, rfc, uri

And is it configurable?  Can I set up Tomcat so that a URL with, say, 200K of query params goes through successfully to the contained servlet?

Yes, I know one should use POST when you have lots of data; that's a less pleasant option in this particular case.  The contained application (a search engine) expects a GET request to perform a search.

Comment: For those that wonder, I actually have the problem of a 12k long WMS Url.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can edit tomcat/conf/server.xml's HTTP/1.1 Connector entry, and add a maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" to increase from the default maximum of 8K or so, to 64K.  I imagine that you could up this number as high as necessary, but 64K suffices for my needs at the moment so I haven't tried it.

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ... />
```

Comment: Very useful, solved my problem with Solr. Seems we were scratching on the default 8192 limit in the `server.xml` config, without noticing, and suddenly hit it. Painful gotcha: nothing nowhere was logged about that, the connections were silently dropped (I don't recall the HTTP Status anymore).

I stumbled over the documentation at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html before, however I didn't associate the `maxHttpHeaderSize` by its name nor its description to be related to the GET request query parameters itself too.

Comment: We also just hit the same limit in Solr, nothing but a blank white page...  :(  The maxHttpHeaderSize did the trick.

Comment: I think the maxHttpHeaderSize="100000" is not possible, it should be in multiply by 1024. I have changed the maxHttpHeaderSize="1048576" which is 1024*1024 and it is still not working.

Comment: An accepted answer, "maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" **does not work** It worked before because of **bug** in Tomcat.
URL/URI has nothing to do with HTTP Headers.

Comment: @FuadEfendi what IS the maximum size now then?

Comment: Original question was "what is the maximum size of URL". HTTP protocol doesn't have "URL"; instead, it has "host" part, and "method" (which could be GET, POST, PUT, etc.); if you need *huge* method use POST which doesn't have any limitations. Server implementations are vendor-specific. Tomcat v.8 uses 2 megabytes for POST (default; but you can configure it 'unlimited'); and 8 kilobytes for GET (default). When you need 'unlimited' POST? For example, if you submit huge HTML FORM with a lot of key-value pairs.

Comment: @FuadEfendi let's say I am in a scenario where the type of method cannot be changed from `GET` to `POST`. In an event like above, is there any way to configure the max URL lengh in tomcat?

Answer (score 6):

The length of an HTTP GET request **is not enforced by RFC2616**, as Microsoft reports for its [IE max length support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427).

So, **the maximum GET length is a client (browser) related issue**. If your app is used by people you can force to use a given browser then you can simply find what is the length this browser support.

In every case I suggest a look to the [Wikypedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#External_links) page about those browser related issues on the Query string (the part of the request bringing parameters for server side apps, the one following the "?" eventually present in a request.

Of course maybe tomcat will put a limit too, on the server side.
RFC says:

> Servers MUST be able to handle the URI
>   of any resource they serve, and SHOULD
>   be able to handle URIs of unbounded
>   length if they provide GET-based forms
>   that could generate such URIs. A
>   server SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI
>   Too Long) status if a URI is longer
>   than the server can handle (see
>   section 10.4.15).

so you can easily test if Tomcat  has a limit and find out what this limit is simply using different requests starting with a very long one giving the error and going down by one half. Then use bisection method to fast find the exact value.

Comment: Albert, I was aware that Tomcat had a limit out of the box (something like 8K); I wondered if there were a limit that even configuration could not overcome.

Answer (score 2):

For AJP connector, you need to adjust the `packetSize` attribute:

```
<Connector port="8009" 
    protocol="AJP/1.3" 
    packetSize="65536" />
```

Comment: If you are using mod_proxy you need to set
`ProxyIOBufferSize 65536` 
in your httpd config too.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the config at Tomcat server ( ..\Tomcat 6.0\conf\server.xml )

```
< Connector port="8983" maxHttpHeaderSize="100000" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by formatting your code and explaining why it answer's OP question.